# Property not updated after SaveChanges (EF database first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

First of all, I would like to say that I read the related posts (notably [EF 4.1 SaveChanges not updating navigation or reference properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517182/ef-4-1-savechanges-not-updating-navigation-or-reference-properties), [Entity Framework Code First - Why can't I update complex properties this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506116/entity-framework-code-first-why-cant-i-update-complex-properties-this-way), and [Entity Framework 4.1 RC (Code First) - Entity not updating over association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507596/entity-framework-4-1-rc-code-first-entity-not-updating-over-association)).

However, I could not solve my problem. I am quite new to Entity Framework so I guess I must have misunderstood those posts answers.
Anyway I would be really grateful is someone could help me understand because I am quite stuck.

I have two tables :

- `Person`
- `Item` with a nullable `PersonId` and a `Type`

An item can have an owner, or not.
Consequently, `Person` has an `Items` property which is an IEnumerable of `Item`.

A person can have one only `Item` by type.
If the person wants to change, he can replace his current item by any other of the same type in his items :

```
public class MyService
{
    private PersonRepo personRepo = new PersonRepo();
    private ItemRepo itemRepo = new ItemRepo();

    public void SwitchItems(Person person, Guid newItemId)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            // Get the entities
            Item newItem = itemRepo.Get(newItemId);
            Item oldItem = person.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Type == newItem.Type)

            // Update the values
            newItem.PersonId = person.Id;
            oldItem.PersonId = null;

            // Add or update entities
            itemRepo.AddOrUpdate(oldItem);
            itemRepo.AddOrUpdate(newItem);
            personRepo.AddOrUpdate(person);

            uof.Commit(); // only does a SaveChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the repositories structure and the `AddOrUpdate` method :

```
public class PersonRepo : RepositoryBase<Person>
{
    ...
}

public class RepositoryBase<TObject> where TObject : class, IEntity
{
    protected MyEntities entities
    {
        get { return UnitOfWork.Current.Context; }
    }

    public virtual void AddOrUpdate(TObject entity)
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            var entry = entities.Entry<IEntity>(entity);

            if (Exists(entity.Id))
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    var set = entities.Set<TObject>();
                    var currentEntry = set.Find(entity.Id);
                    if (currentEntry != null)
                    {
                        var attachedEntry = entities.Entry(currentEntry);
                        attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        set.Attach(entity);
                        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                }
                else
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works pretty well and the old and the new items' `PersonId` properties are correctly updated in database.
However, if I check `person.Items` after the `SaveChanges()`, the old item still appears instead of the new one and I need it to be correct in order to update the page's controls values.

Although I read the posts with the same issue I could not resolve it...
I tried lots of things, notably calling `entities.Entry(person).Collection(p => p.Items).Load()` but got an exception each time I tried.

If somebody has any idea please feel free, I can add some more code if needed.

Thanks a lot !

***EDIT : UnitOfWork***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;

public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private const string _httpContextKey = "_unitOfWork";
    private MyEntities _dbContext;

    public static UnitOfWork Current
    {
        get { return (UnitOfWork)HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey]; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey] = this;
    }

    public MyEntities Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dbContext == null)
                _dbContext = new MyEntities();

            return _dbContext;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_dbContext != null)
            _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

***Two solutions that worked***

**Solution 1 (reload from context after SaveChanges)**

```
public partial class MyPage
{
    private MyService service;
    private Person person;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        service = new MyService();
        person = service.GetCurrentPerson(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        ...
    }

    protected void SelectNewItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Guid itemId = Guid.Parse(((Button)sender).Attributes["id"]);

        service.SelectNewItem(person, itemId);

        UpdatePage();
    }

    private void UpdatePage()
    {
        if (person != null)
            person = service.GetCurrentPerson(Request.QueryString["id"]);

        // Update controls values using person's properties here
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private PersonRepo personRepo = new PersonRepo();
    private ItemRepo itemRepo = new ItemRepo();

    public void SwitchItems(Person person, Guid newItemId)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            // Get the entities
            Item newItem = itemRepo.Get(newItemId);
            Item oldItem = person.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Type == newItem.Type)

            // Update the values
            newItem.PersonId = person.Id;
            oldItem.PersonId = null;

            // Add or update entities
            itemRepo.AddOrUpdate(oldItem);
            itemRepo.AddOrUpdate(newItem);
            personRepo.AddOrUpdate(person);

            uof.Commit(); // only does a SaveChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 (update database AND property)**

```
public partial class MyPage
{
    private MyService service;
    private Person person;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        service = new MyService();
        person = service.GetCurrentPerson(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        ...
    }

    protected void SelectNewItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Guid itemId = Guid.Parse(((Button)sender).Attributes["id"]);

        service.SelectNewItem(person, itemId);

        UpdatePage();
    }

    private void UpdatePage()
    {
        // Update controls values using person's properties here
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private PersonRepo personRepo = new PersonRepo();
    private ItemRepo itemRepo = new ItemRepo();

    public void SwitchItems(Person person, Guid newItemId)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            // Get the entities
            Item newItem = itemRepo.Get(newItemId);
            Item oldItem = person.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Type == newItem.Type)

            // Update the values
            newItem.PersonId = person.Id;
            oldItem.PersonId = null;
            person.Items.Remove(oldItem);
            person.Items.Add(newItem);

            // Add or update entities
            itemRepo.AddOrUpdate(oldItem);
            itemRepo.AddOrUpdate(newItem);
            personRepo.AddOrUpdate(person);

            uof.Commit(); // only does a SaveChanges()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that changing the foreign key on an entity triggers EF to place it in the correct collection. What happens if you spin up a new context and reload from the db?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes if I reload it from database it works (it also works after the following Page_Load by the way). If I check `Item currentItem = entities.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.PersonId == person.Id && i.TypeId == newItem.TypeId);` right after SaveChanges, `currentItem` is perfectly okay. But I would really need the property to be up to date in order to update the page controls. Currently I need to refresh the page (pass by Page_Load and reload the current person) to see that the item has changed.

Comment: @jlvaquero : Of course, I edited my first post with the UnitOfWork code :)

Comment: I suggest if you want to remove the `Item` from the person's items collection then just remove it from the collection while it is being tracked by the context, this will null the foreign key when `SaveChanges` is called. I would say this is more of a ORM way of doing things rather than working with foreign keys

Comment: You mean doing `person.Items.Remove(oldItem); person.Items.Add(newItem)` instead of `newItem.PersonId = person.Id; oldItem.PersonId = null;` ?

Comment: yeah, if the foreign key is nullable it will be set to null when you call savechanges. Otherwise you would have to add to a new collection or remove it.

Comment: Agree with user2697817. You are bypassing ORM spirit trying to manage your entities and FK at low level.

Comment: I just tested : `person.Items.Remove(oldItem); person.Items.Add(newItem)` but this does not update the database, thus after the following Page_Load the old item is back. However doing both works : `newItem.PersonId = person.Id; oldItem.PersonId = null; person.Items.Remove(oldItem); person.Items.Add(newItem)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about refreshing your context to make sure you have the latest db changes after the `.SaveChanges()` method. Pass in the entity to be refreshed an call `Refresh` on the context:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entityPassed);
```

Or leave the `Commit()` method as is and use a more dynamic approach something like:

```
var changedEntities = (from item in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                        EntityState.Added
                                       | EntityState.Deleted
                                       | EntityState.Modified
                                       | EntityState.Unchanged)
                              where item.EntityKey != null
                              select item.Entity);

    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, changedEntities);
```

The `RefreshMode.StoreWins` simply indicates that the database (store) takes priority and will override client (in-memory) changes.

If the Refresh method does not work, you can consider the following:

```
public void RefreshEntity(T entity)
{
  _dbContext.Entry<T>(entity).Reload();
}
```

Or if all else fails, keep it simple and `Dispose` of your DbContext once you're done with each transaction (In this case after `SaveChanges()` has been called). Then if you need to use results after a commit, treat it as a new transaction and, instantiating a fresh DbContext and load your necessary data again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply ! However I am not sure that I understood well : I could leave the `Commit()` method as it is and create an `RefreshEntity()` method that would do `_dbContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entityPassed);`. Is that right ?

Comment: It seems I've misread your comment. I apologise. Yes the `RefreshEntity` method approach should work well!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it right away. However, my `_dbcontext` does not have a `Refresh()` method, nor `ObjectStateManager`. I don't know if it may be important but the `MyEntities` type is inherited from `DbContext`

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer. See if you can access your `Refresh()` method now?

Comment: Yes that does the trick, thanks :) I edited my first post with the method I tried (I added the refresh after the `SaveChanges()` in the `Commit()` method), unfortunately this does not seem to work, the database is correct but `person.Items` is not updated. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Make sure `person` is in the `changedEntities` collection when calling `Refresh`. Alternatively, you can try reload a specific entity? See edited answer.

Comment: Just calling `_dbContext.Entry<T>(entity).Reload();` on `person` entity after `uof.Commit()` I had an exception saying that the entity didn't exist in the context, so I made as the new edit in the first post. No exception anymore however same behaviour : the `person.Items` remains unchanged until the following database access in `Page_Load`. I'm quite desperate : (

Comment: Only things that works is either do a `person = entities.Get(person.Id)` after the `uof.Commit()` (that's to say retrieve the current person and all his dependencies from DB but that's really ugly), or `newItem.PersonId = person.Id; oldItem.PersonId = null; person.Items.Remove(oldItem); person.Items.Add(newItem)` but does not seems a little a good method either...

Comment: If all of the above hasn't worked, I'm sorry to say that the only other option I can think of is to dispose and re-instantiate your context after the `SaveChanges()`. This way you wont have in-memory cache and your context is guaranteed to be "the latest".

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I edited the first post with the two solutions which work : The first one is yours (open a new context and get back the updated entity), and the second is about updating both database and property. Which one do you think would be best (mainly talking about logic and performances) ?

Comment: If you can add your opinion about what would be the best solution in your answer, then I'll accept it so it can help other people ! ;)

Comment: Performance wise, I guess your second option may save a db call making it faster but does feel more like a hack? Personally I would go with instantiating a new Context. It feels cleaner and less "state-dependent". A context is created, some transactions done and context disposed. Next transactions will then never be affected by any prior state. Up to you in the end :)

Comment: I agree, seems like patching up. I'll keep on with the first solution then, and will look for another way if it really does have performances issues. Anyway thanks a lot for the time you spent explaining me, I'm so grateful. Would you please add a second EDIT to your answer to explain your final proposition (instantiating a new context) ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Transection for example. 
It's working fine.

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
 {

    public readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    private readonly IDbTransaction _transaction;
    private readonly ObjectContext _objectContext;

      public UnitOfWork(DatabaseContext context)
      {
        _context = context as DatabaseContext ?? new DatabaseContext ();
        this._objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this._context).ObjectContext;
        if (this._objectContext.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this._objectContext.Connection.Open();
            this._transaction = _objectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        }
      }             

    public int Complete()
    {
        int result = 0;
        try
        {
            result = _context.SaveChanges();
            this._transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Rollback();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void Rollback()
    {
        this._transaction.Rollback();

        foreach (var entry in this._context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
                    break;
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:
                    entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
                    break;
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted:
                    entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this._objectContext.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            this._objectContext.Connection.Close();
        }
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```